# elasticsearch group-by multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, elasticsearch-query

I am Looking for the best way to group data in elasticsearch.
Elasticsearch doesn't support something like 'group by' in sql.

Lets say I have 1k categories and millions of products. What do you think is the best way to render a complete category tree? Off course you need some metadata (icon, link-target, seo-titles,...) and custom sorting for the categories.

1. Using Aggregations:
   Example: https://found.no/play/gist/8124563
   Looks usable if you have to group by one field, and need some extra fields.
2. Using multiple Fields in a Facet (won't work):
   Example: https://found.no/play/gist/1aa44e2114975384a7c2
   Here we lose the relationship between the different fields.
3. Building funny Facets:
   https://found.no/play/gist/8124810

For example, building a category tree using these 3 "solutions" sucks.
Solution 1 May work (ES 1 isn't stable right now)
Solution 2 Doesn't work 
Solution 3 Is a pain because it feels ugly, you need to prepare a lot of data and the facets blow up.

Maybe an alternative could be not to store any category data in ES, just the id
https://found.no/play/gist/a53e46c91e2bf077f2e1

Then you could get the associated category from another system, like redis, memcache or the database.

This would end up in clean code, but the performance could become a problem.
For example loading, 1k Categories from Memcache / Redis / a database could be slow.
Another problem is that syncing 2 database is harder than syncing one.

How do you deal with such problems?

I am sorry for the links, but I can't post more than 2 in one article.

Answer (score 38):

The aggregations API allows grouping by multiple fields, using *sub-aggregations*. Suppose you want to group by fields `field1`, `field2` and `field3`:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "field2"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field3"
              }
            }
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course this can go on for as many fields as you'd like.

**Update:**
For completeness, here is how the output of the above query looks. Also below is python code for generating the aggregation query and flattening the result into a list of dictionaries.

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "agg1": {
      "buckets": [{
        "doc_count": <count>,
        "key": <value of field1>,
        "agg2": {
          "buckets": [{
            "doc_count": <count>,
            "key": <value of field2>,
            "agg3": {
              "buckets": [{
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              },
              {
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              }, ...
              ]
            },
            {
            "doc_count": <count>,
            "key": <value of field2>,
            "agg3": {
              "buckets": [{
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              },
              {
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              }, ...
              ]
            }, ...
          ]
        },
        {
        "doc_count": <count>,
        "key": <value of field1>,
        "agg2": {
          "buckets": [{
            "doc_count": <count>,
            "key": <value of field2>,
            "agg3": {
              "buckets": [{
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              },
              {
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              }, ...
              ]
            },
            {
            "doc_count": <count>,
            "key": <value of field2>,
            "agg3": {
              "buckets": [{
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              },
              {
                "doc_count": <count>,
                "key": <value of field3>
              }, ...
              ]
            }, ...
          ]
        }, ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The following python code performs the group-by given the list of fields. I you specify `include_missing=True`, it also includes combinations of values where some of the fields are missing (you don't need it if you have version 2.0 of Elasticsearch thanks to [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11042))

```py
def group_by(es, fields, include_missing):
    current_level_terms = {'terms': {'field': fields[0]}}
    agg_spec = {fields[0]: current_level_terms}

    if include_missing:
        current_level_missing = {'missing': {'field': fields[0]}}
        agg_spec[fields[0] + '_missing'] = current_level_missing

    for field in fields[1:]:
        next_level_terms = {'terms': {'field': field}}
        current_level_terms['aggs'] = {
            field: next_level_terms,
        }

        if include_missing:
            next_level_missing = {'missing': {'field': field}}
            current_level_terms['aggs'][field + '_missing'] = next_level_missing
            current_level_missing['aggs'] = {
                field: next_level_terms,
                field + '_missing': next_level_missing,
            }
            current_level_missing = next_level_missing

        current_level_terms = next_level_terms

    agg_result = es.search(body={'aggs': agg_spec})['aggregations']
    return get_docs_from_agg_result(agg_result, fields, include_missing)


def get_docs_from_agg_result(agg_result, fields, include_missing):
    current_field = fields[0]
    buckets = agg_result[current_field]['buckets']
    if include_missing:
        buckets.append(agg_result[(current_field + '_missing')])

    if len(fields) == 1:
        return [
            {
                current_field: bucket.get('key'),
                'doc_count': bucket['doc_count'],
            }
            for bucket in buckets if bucket['doc_count'] > 0
        ]

    result = []
    for bucket in buckets:
        records = get_docs_from_agg_result(bucket, fields[1:], include_missing)
        value = bucket.get('key')
        for record in records:
            record[current_field] = value
        result.extend(records)

    return result
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use **Composite Aggregation** query as follows. This type of query also paginates the results if the number of buckets exceeds from the normal value of ES. By using the field 'after' you can access the rest of buckets:

```
"aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "field1": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field1"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "field2": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field2"
              }
            }
          },
         {
            "field3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field3"
              }
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

You can find more detail in ES page [bucket-composite-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).

Comment: es supports composite-aggregation after version 6.1

Answer (score 5):

I think some developers will be definitely looking same implementation in Spring DATA ES and JAVA ES API.

Please finds :-

```
List<FieldObject> fieldObjectList = Lists.newArrayList();
    SearchQuery aSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery()).withIndices(indexName).withTypes(type)
            .addAggregation(
                    terms("ByField1").field("field1").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("ByField2").field("field2")
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("ByField3").field("field3")))
                    )
            .build();
    Aggregations aField1Aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(aSearchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse aResponse) {
            return aResponse.getAggregations();
        }
    });
    Terms aField1Terms = aField1Aggregations.get("ByField1");
    aField1Terms.getBuckets().stream().forEach(aField1Bucket -> {
        String field1Value = aField1Bucket.getKey();
        Terms aField2Terms = aField1Bucket.getAggregations().get("ByField2");

        aField2Terms.getBuckets().stream().forEach(aField2Bucket -> {
            String field2Value = aField2Bucket.getKey();
            Terms aField3Terms = aField2Bucket.getAggregations().get("ByField3");

            aField3Terms.getBuckets().stream().forEach(aField3Bucket -> {
                String field3Value = aField3Bucket.getKey();
                Long count = aField3Bucket.getDocCount();

                FieldObject fieldObject = new FieldObject();
                fieldObject.setField1(field1Value);
                fieldObject.setField2(field2Value);
                fieldObject.setField3(field3Value);
                fieldObject.setCount(count);
                fieldObjectList.add(fieldObject);
            });
        });
    });
```

imports need to be done for same :-

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery;
import static org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders.terms; 
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.common.collect.Lists;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.TermFilterBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.InternalFilter;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.Terms;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ResultsExtractor;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

sub-aggregations is what you need .. though this is never explicitly stated in the docs it can be found implicitly by  [structuring aggregations](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations)

It will result the sub-aggregation as if the query was filtered by result of  the higher aggregation. 
It actually looks like  as if this is what happens in there.

```
{
"aggregations": {
    "VALUE1AGG": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "VALUE1",
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "VALUE2AGG": {
           "terms": {
             "field": "VALUE2",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```