# ElasticSearch : Aggregate on the Filtered Unique records

Tags: elasticsearch

I am struck with an issue in ElasticSearch.

I are trying to get unique documents from the filtered data set and do an aggregation on top of it.

Our data set looks something like this..
**ID    object  Property1   Property2**
12  123 Test1   Fest2
23  234 Test3   Fest4
5   123 Test1   Fest2
55  123 Test2   Fest4
3   234 Test2   Fest2

I  could like to filter the devices based on property2  and aggregate (group by) on property1 of the unique filtered records. 
Could someone help me on this?

Filtering and getting unique records.

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "query": { "match": { "Property2": "Fest2" }},
"aggs": {
    "Unique-Object": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "object.keyword",
        "size": 20
},
"aggs": {
    "top_uids_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
}'
```

I could like to group by Property1 as below on the output of the above DSL…Could some one throw light on this?

Group by Property1

```
"aggs": {
"Property1_count": {
"terms": {
"field": " Property1.keyword"
}
```

Thanks
Arun S

Comment: Could you plz make  sql query for your requirement , so your question will be clear ? .

Comment: Thanks. Raw Sql query is something like this..select count(DISTINCT id) from table where Property2='xxx' group by property1

Comment: Updated my answer , i think us should use two group by on id and property  1 . Check with your test data . I have tested in my system .

Comment: Thanks vijay. it works..

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be your query . check using this , agg inside agg :-
Use of cardinality [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html) .

```
  {
    "_source":false,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Property2": "xxxx"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "byProperty1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "property1"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "byId": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For java implementation , check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647596/2357869) .
Check this question group by on multiple fields [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775040/elasticsearch-group-by-multiple-fields/42647596#42647596) .