# Elasticsearch aggregation using a bool filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I've the following query which works fine on Elasticsearch `1.x` but does not work on `2.x` (I get `doc_count: 0`) since the [bool filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) has been deprecated. It's not quite clear to me how to re-write this query using the new [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "events_per_period": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "message.facility": [
                  "facility1",
                  "facility2",
                  "facility3"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was your previous query?

Comment: @AndreiStefan - The query I've above is one I've that returns `doc_count > 0` in 1.x but returns 0 in 2.x.

Comment: Can you also share the mapping of the `message` field and a sample document?

Comment: mappings for message field, is it a nested field or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want aggregation on multi fields with filter  :-
Here I assume filter for id and aggregation on facility1 and facility2 .

```
{
    "_source":false,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "id": "value"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "byFacility1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "facility1"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "byFacility2": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "facility2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you want aggregation on three field , check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775040/elasticsearch-group-by-multiple-fields).
For java implementation [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42647596/2357869)