# Pagination with group by on three items of index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using AWS ElasticSearch V6.4, here's my index

```
{
  "jobs": {
"aliases": {},
"mappings": {
  "Job": {
    "properties": {
      "area": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "childUpdate": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "cityName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "companyId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "companyLogo": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "companyName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "countryName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "dateExpired": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "designation": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "experienceYears": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "fullName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "industryId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "industryName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "jobPublished": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "jobStatus": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "jobType": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "numberOfCandidatesShortlisted": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "number_of_applications": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "primarySkills": {
        "properties": {
          "orderNumber": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "reasonForClosing": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "resume": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "salary": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "salaryTo": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "salaryType": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "samejobs": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "stateName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "normalize": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "updateAt": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "designation": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "fullName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "profileImageUrl": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "userId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "utmSource": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "provided_name": "jobs",
    "creation_date": "1556099156261",
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "tcNbMSODSD-LoIlei0NrpA",
    "version": {
      "created": "6040299"
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

I want to group by on userId, title, companyId with count.

I have tried adding one more item(let say samejobs) and add the total count of group by and searching based on that item and ignoring all other items.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
"_source": {
    "includes": [],
    "excludes": ["status", "countryId", "stateId", "cityId"]
},
"sort": [{
    "updatedAt": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
}],
"from": 0,
"size": 100,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "jobStatus": {
                    "value": "active"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "status": {
                    "value": "active"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "dateExpired": {
                    "gt": 1568007661898
                }
            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "samejobs": {
                    "gt": 0
                }
            }
        }, {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "sales executive",
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "fields": ["title", "industryName", "primarySkills.value.keyword", "secondarySkills"]
            }
        }, {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Rajkot",
                        "type": "phrase_prefix",
                        "fields": ["area", "cityName"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }],
        "must_not": [],
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "15000km",
                "location": {
                    "lat": 23.0066678,
                    "lon": 72.5017585
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want the results to be group by userId, companyId & title with pagination. If the approach i am doing is wrong then please suggest the best way to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775040/elasticsearch-group-by-multiple-fields -- check this.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal i want  hits object to be paginated. this only gives me count of aggregation.